# programmatically edit, filter and save the data from each text file in large file list in R?

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have downloaded historical weather data of Germany which are stored in 1080 `txt` file in total (original data can be found in this ftp: [German weather historical data](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/)), where each individual weather station's data is stored in respective individual `txt` format file.

However, in my research case, I only need to keep weather data record between `01-01-1980 ~ 31-12-2014` in each file, where each individual text file contains weather data that more than above-specified date interval (about 100 years weather data (not continuous)). It is gonna be quite inefficient and hard work if I edit each `txt` file manually and only keep weather data record only from `01-01-1980`  to `31-12-2014`. Perhaps there might be a way to edit each text file programmatically where only keep weather data record that satisfies my specified date range while rest of the data record must be deleted and file can be saved with its original format and name.

I downloaded all data record in .txt format and loaded them in my R session. I can able to read them. But programmatically edit and keep only weather data record that I am interested in is unknown to me. How can I make this happen easily in R? Is that doable to do this in R?

Here is how data looks like:

```
> head(ClmData_files)
[1] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_17190101_20161231_00403.txt"
[2] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_17570301_19611130_01425.txt"
[3] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_17810101_20161231_02290.txt"
[4] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_17880101_20161231_05099.txt"
[5] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_17920101_19840731_04927.txt"
[6] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_18010101_19531231_03382.txt"
> tail(ClmData_files)
[1] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_20110901_20161231_00161.txt"
[2] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_20131101_20161231_15207.txt"
[3] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_20140901_20161231_15444.txt"
[4] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_20150801_20161231_01246.txt"
[5] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_20160501_20161231_15555.txt"
[6] "stella/data/germany_histData/produkt_klima_monat_20160901_20161231_01886.txt"
> length(ClmData_files)
[1] 1080
```

Here is how each individual text file looks like in `Notepad++` (just first 10 row):

```
STATIONS_ID;MESS_DATUM_BEGINN;MESS_DATUM_ENDE;QN_4;MO_N;MO_TT;MO_TX;MO_TN;MO_FK;MX_TX;MX_FX;MX_TN;MO_SD_S;QN_6;MO_RR;MX_RS;eor
        403;17190101;17190131;    5;  -999;   2.8;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190201;17190228;    5;  -999;   1.1;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190301;17190331;    5;  -999;   5.2;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190401;17190430;    5;  -999;   9.0;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190501;17190531;    5;  -999;  15.1;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190601;17190630;    5;  -999;  19.0;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190701;17190731;    5;  -999;  21.4;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190801;17190831;    5;  -999;  18.8;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190901;17190930;    5;  -999;  13.9;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17191001;17191031;    5;  -999;   9.0;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
```

After I download all weather data from above ftp server on my local drive and read them in R down below:

```
lapply(ClmData_files, function(x) {
  read.table(x,
             sep="\t",
             fill=FALSE,
             strip.white=TRUE)
})
```

Because each `txt` file has nearly 100 years weather data, but I am only interested in recent 35 years to study future climate change trend by using regression model. Now I need to access each txt file programmatically and edit and filter weather data record based on customized date interval and saved them in current R session. Is there any way to make this happen in dynamic R programming? Any thoughts?

**Update**:

we only need to work with `MESS_DATUM_BEGINN (begin date);MESS_DATUM_ENDE (end date)` columns in each file and only keep weather data record that falls in date interval `1980-01-01 ~ 2014-12-31` and save them in `csv` format, such operation must be applied and extended to all `txt` file (1080 files in total). How can I make this happen programmatically in R? Any idea? Thanks

**Update 2**:

Now I am able to download all historical weather data of Germany by using `rdwd` package, here is code that grab all data in R session:

```
install.packages("rdwd")
library(rdwd)
ftpURL <- selectDWD(name = "", exactmatch = TRUE, 
                    res="monthly", 
                    var="kl", per="historical", current = TRUE)
ftpFile <- dataDWD(file = ftpURL, dir = "stella/input/",sleep = 0)
rowData <- readDWD(ftpFile, fread = FALSE)
```

Now respective historical weather data are on the fly: [german historical weather data](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC)

Comment: start by making sure you can load a single txt file in correctly. I don't think you're getting what you want with that call.

Comment: You're separating on a tab, but your data is separated with a semicolon

Comment: This is the work of getting and cleaning data. Yes, it's doable, and there are strategies for making it less painful, but they require careful planning, and there is not a single approach. Generally it involves paying attention, noticing patterns, and using `mapply`. Carefully read the documentation for `read.table` to start.

Comment: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: Start working on it and when you have a specific question about your code (why it isn't doing what you'd like it to do) ask that here :) Start by carefully reading the documentation for `read.table`, though.

Comment: this is not a code writing service

Comment: You might also notice that the span is encoded in hte file name. So `ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/monatswerte_KL_00061_19750701_19780831_hist.zip` would not be appropriate for you purposes.

Comment: @42- Thanks for your comment. I noticed that `rdwd` package can download all historical weather data. Any update to get this done in R? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options, but they all start with knowing how to read in a table correctly. As was mentioned in the comments, you are trying to use a tab character is the delimiter, when it seems obvious that the data is semicolon-delimited, so though there *may* be tabs in there, you are likely inadvertently getting multiple columns combined.

So let's first read in just one file. Note that I'm using `text='...'`, whereas you should be using `file='...'` ... it's just shorthand for reproducible SO answers.

```
x <- read.table(text = 'STATIONS_ID;MESS_DATUM_BEGINN;MESS_DATUM_ENDE;QN_4;MO_N;MO_TT;MO_TX;MO_TN;MO_FK;MX_TX;MX_FX;MX_TN;MO_SD_S;QN_6;MO_RR;MX_RS;eor
        403;17190101;17190131;    5;  -999;   2.8;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190201;17190228;    5;  -999;   1.1;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190301;17190331;    5;  -999;   5.2;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190401;17190430;    5;  -999;   9.0;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190501;17190531;    5;  -999;  15.1;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190601;17190630;    5;  -999;  19.0;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190701;17190731;    5;  -999;  21.4;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190801;17190831;    5;  -999;  18.8;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17190901;17190930;    5;  -999;  13.9;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor
        403;17191001;17191031;    5;  -999;   9.0;   -999;   -999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;eor',
        sep = ';', header = TRUE)
str(x)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  17 variables:
#  $ STATIONS_ID      : int  403 403 403 403 403 403 403 403 403 403
#  $ MESS_DATUM_BEGINN: int  17190101 17190201 17190301 17190401 17190501 17190601 17190701 17190801 17190901 17191001
#  $ MESS_DATUM_ENDE  : int  17190131 17190228 17190331 17190430 17190531 17190630 17190731 17190831 17190930 17191031
#  $ QN_4             : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
#  $ MO_N             : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MO_TT            : num  2.8 1.1 5.2 9 15.1 19 21.4 18.8 13.9 9
#  $ MO_TX            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MO_TN            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MO_FK            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MX_TX            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MX_FX            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MX_TN            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MO_SD_S          : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ QN_6             : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MO_RR            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ MX_RS            : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
#  $ eor              : Factor w/ 1 level "eor": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Next, we can either parse all dates into classic R `Date` objects, or we can deal with them directly as the integers they are now; the comparison will likely work either way, but for code clarity (and because I suspect you may want to do further analysis/visualization with actual date-like labeling) I'm going to do the extra step of converting to proper date objects:

```
my_ymd <- function(a) as.Date(as.character(a), format='%Y%m%d')
x[c('MESS_DATUM_BEGINN','MESS_DATUM_ENDE')] <- lapply(x[c('MESS_DATUM_BEGINN','MESS_DATUM_ENDE')], my_ymd)
str(x[c('MESS_DATUM_BEGINN','MESS_DATUM_ENDE')])
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ MESS_DATUM_BEGINN: Date, format: "1719-01-01" "1719-02-01" "1719-03-01" "1719-04-01" ...
#  $ MESS_DATUM_ENDE  : Date, format: "1719-01-31" "1719-02-28" "1719-03-31" "1719-04-30" ...
```

(There are several packages out there that do this quickly and with more robustness. Feel free to use any of them, I'm providing a simple base-R approach  given what I see.)

From here, filtering out the date range you want is very straight-forward (note that I'm using different dates, since your example does not include the dates you want to filter on):

```
keep_ymd <- my_ymd(c("17190401", "17190701"))
keep_ymd
# [1] "1719-04-01" "1719-07-01"
x[keep_ymd[1] <= x$MESS_DATUM_BEGINN & x$MESS_DATUM_ENDE <= keep_ymd[2],,drop=FALSE]
#   STATIONS_ID MESS_DATUM_BEGINN MESS_DATUM_ENDE QN_4 MO_N MO_TT MO_TX MO_TN MO_FK MX_TX MX_FX MX_TN MO_SD_S QN_6 MO_RR MX_RS eor
# 4         403        1719-04-01      1719-04-30    5 -999   9.0  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999    -999 -999  -999  -999 eor
# 5         403        1719-05-01      1719-05-31    5 -999  15.1  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999    -999 -999  -999  -999 eor
# 6         403        1719-06-01      1719-06-30    5 -999  19.0  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999    -999 -999  -999  -999 eor
```

So to combine this with your initial code using `lapply`, I'd probably do something like:

```
rawdata <- lapply(ClmData_files, read.table, sep=';', header=TRUE)
filtered <- lapply(rawdata, function(x) {
  x[c('MESS_DATUM_BEGINN','MESS_DATUM_ENDE')] <- lapply(x[c('MESS_DATUM_BEGINN','MESS_DATUM_ENDE')], my_ymd)
  x[keep_ymd[1] <= x$MESS_DATUM_BEGINN & x$MESS_DATUM_ENDE <= keep_ymd[2],,drop=FALSE]
})
```

(I tend to load raw data and keep it around until I'm confident that my first few steps are solid.)

**Edit**

I think (untested) the following `dplyr` (and friends) pipeline might work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

data_frame(fname = ClmData_files) %>%
  mutate(data = map(fname, ~ read.table(., sep=':', header=TRUE))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(MESS_DATUM_BEGINN, MESS_DATUM_ENDE), funs(my_ymd)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(
    between(MESS_DATUM_BEGINN, keep_ymd[1], keep_ymd[2]),
    between(MESS_DATUM_ENDE, keep_ymd[1], keep_ymd[2])
  )
```